# Having trouble with retry connection implementation

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Something wrong with this code?
It doesn't return `true`. Always an instant `false` return.

```
public boolean chkCon() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();
            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            return code == 200;
        } catch (Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If i set:

```
public boolean chkCon() {
  return true;  // it works
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because an exception is occurring. The problem with your code is you have a network call on Main Thread. To avoid that exception to be occurred, use below code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new MyAsyncTasck().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}

public class MyAsyncTasck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        return chkCon();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        String result = "Your result is " + aBoolean;
    }
}

public boolean chkCon() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();
        int code = connection.getResponseCode();
        return code == 200;
    } catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

}
Hope that helps you.

Comment: I got it. Thank you

Comment: I am glad that helped you. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Check for an active internet connection like this:

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}
```

To check a specific server is up:

```
// Host to check
String host = "http://www.google.com/";
//Timeout in millis
int timeout = 30000;
if(InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut)){
    //Successful ping
}else{
    //Unsuccessful ping
}
```

Comment: It won't work if the app server is down. I should ping that server

Comment: Okay, understood. I've edited my answer to include that now :)